# If Column D is Direct, Sumproduct(E,F)

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I have a worksheet set up like what is below, can someone tell me how to sumproduct columns E and F when column D = "Direct"?

```
Column D  Column E  Column F
Direct     $500       1
Indirect   $250       3
Direct     $100       4
Indirect   $600       8
Indirect   $1100      2
```

Answers should be 
Direct = $900

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$6="Direct")*$E$2:$E$6,$F$2:$F$6)
```

[image]